# ContentControl's ContentPresenter is blank?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In XAML I'm trying to create a very simple 'content container' that contains a random element (in this case it's a `TextBlock`), but the following content is just blank, and doesn't contain the `TextBlock` element specified.

Is `ContentControl` the correct element to use in this scenario?

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
    </ContentControl.Content>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Background="Red">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: @Clemens I've got a `StaticResource` that could be anything. I want to presenter *whatever* that may be, inside a red border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `TargetType="ContentControl"` on the ControlTemplate:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
    </ContentControl.Content>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl"> <!-- here -->
            <Border Background="Red">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

---

To make it reusable, you could declare a ContentControl Style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="RedBorderContentControlStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use it like this:

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource RedBorderContentControlStyle}">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
</ContentControl>
```